# Having trouble creating arbitrary new Object, parametrized for function call

Tags: object, ocaml

I wanted this kind of expression in OCaml

```
let wrapper obj f = fun raw -> f (new obj raw)
```

But I get a compiler error of `Unbound class obj` but so what, why isn't the compiler satisfied with creating this function which just says call a function on this object which happens to take one init arg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a function that constructs the object. For a one-argument class `foo` you can use `new foo` to get that function.

```
let wrapper make_obj f raw = f (make_obj raw)

class foo (x) = object
  method y = x + 1
end

let answer = wrapper (new foo) (fun o -> o#y) 2
```

Here, `wrapper` has a very general type that doesn't mention objects at all. If you want to make it clear that an object constructor is expected as the argument, you can restrict the type with an annotation:

```
let wrapper (make_obj: (_ -> < .. >)) f raw = f (make_obj raw)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this is that an OCaml class is a type, not a value. So you can't write a function in OCaml that accepts a class as a parameter.

Here's a session:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# class abc = object method m = 12 end;;
class abc : object method m : int end
# abc;;
Error: Unbound value abc
# let f (x: abc) = x#m ;;
val f : abc -> int = <fun>
# f (new abc);;
- : int = 12
```

As you can see, `abc` is a type. Not a value.

In other languages, classes are values. But not in OCaml.

Comment: Why can't we say something like this function works for all all objects that take one init? Isn't the obj just a placeholder and we could tell from the type signature if the provided object will unify...I'm still unconvinced.